# Why whiny_nils in production is set to false by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Calling id on nil gave error in my development environment, but in the production it silently returns 4. Developer might go unaware of this.

So, is there any specific reason, why the whiny_nils is not set to true by default in production environment?

Will there be any problem, if we set it to true in production?

Comment: @NARKOZ, I use, 
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-01-04 mbari 8/0x8770 on patchlevel 357) [i486-linux]
Rails 3.0.20

Comment: are you using a `rescue` block? Any code anywhere that looks similar to this? `Rails.env.production?`

Answer (score 0):

Calling the methods on `nil` that `whiny_nils` complains about is often indicative of either a bug in the code or a problem with the data it's being run on - something is `nil` that the developer didn't expect to be. In a development environment, the thing to do is let the developer know about this, so that they can check whether it's supposed to be doing that.
Production code, however, wants to run with as few errors as possible, so the default assumption there is that if you're calling `.id` on `nil`, it's intentional and you know what you're doing - it's not a syntax error, so we let it go.

If you set `whiny_nils` to `true` on production, you'll probably get more errors in your production site, which is obviously a problem. On the other hand, if you're not intentionally calling `.id` on `nil`, maybe a user seeing an error is better than getting unexpected behavior from `nil.id` being 4.